# Why did they say Han Solo's carbon freezing has never been attempted before?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

I did not check on the details, but I remember that the whole point of carbon freezing Han Solo is to test the carbon freezing technique - which is claimed to have never been done on a living organism - to make sure Luke Skywalker can be frozen and brought to Palpatine intact and unharmed.

But this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcerfE89IIc) from the Clone Wars show that it has been done before, and it is possible that such a technique, while probably not recommended, is not unheard of. So why did they say that Han is the first, in-universe?